# url routing with web config in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
  <rule name="Rewriteaspx" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="reservations/reservation.aspx$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="reservations/reservation.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="removeextension" enabled="true">
    <match url="reservations/reservation" negate="false" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="reservations/reservation.aspx" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="Rewriteaspx1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="reservations/reservation" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="&amp;?(token=[^&amp;]+)&amp;?" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="reservations/reservation.aspx" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="reservations/reservation.aspx?{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
  </rule>
```

this is my code. this code hide url extension . But not work append my url with query string

Comment: what exactly do you wish to achieve ?

Comment: Url extension hide and show my url with query string i.e http://localhost:56966/reservations/reservation this my url with out extension.But i want to my url this type http://localhost:56966/reservations/reservation/?44545/$$ggj      (use web config file in asp.net)

Comment: @LalitMehra Please help me